# Regexp for specific matching of character string

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I need a regex to match something like

"4f0f30500be4443126002034"

and

"4f0f30500be4443126002034>4f0f31310be4443126005578"

but not like

"4f0f30500be4443126002034>4f0f31310be4443126005578>4f0f31310be4443126005579"

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what should and shouldn't match? Why does the 3rd one not match? Because it consists of 3 numbers?

Comment: Yes. I want to only match the string of two numbers, not three.

Comment: Well, the string of one or two numbers, not three. To be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^[\da-f]{24}(>[\da-f]{24})?$
```

`[\da-f]{24}` is exactly 24 characters consisting only of 0-9, a-f. The whole pattern is one such number optionally followed by a > and a second such number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
/^[0-9a-f]{24}(>[0-9a-f]{24})?$/
```

That matches 24 characters in the `0-9a-f` range (which matches your first string) followed by zero or one strings starting with a `>`, followed by 24 characters in the `0-9a-f` range (which matches your second string). [Here's a RegexPal for this regex](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5E%5B0-9a-f%5D%7B24%7D%28%3E%5B0-9a-f%5D%7B24%7D%29%3F%24&input=4f0f30500be4443126002034%0A4f0f30500be4443126002034%3E4f0f31310be4443126005578%0A4f0f30500be4443126002034%3E4f0f31310be4443126005578%3E4f0f31310be4443126005579%0A).

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a regex.

`str = "4f0f30500be4443126002034>4f0f31310be4443126005578"`

`match = str.count('>') < 2`

match will be set to true for matches where there are 1 or 0 '>' in the string. Otherwise match is set to false.