# Regex for this particular pattern

Tags: regex

I have three different things

```
xxx
xxx>xxx
xxx>xxx>xxx
```

Where xxx can be any combination of letters and number

I need a regex that can match the first two but NOT the third.

Comment: Are these three different "things" all that there is in the string, or are you trying to find those in a larger string?

Comment: Do you only want to match the `xxx`s or also the `>`? In other words, are you trying to extract the `xxx`s?

Comment: How is this question different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854363/regexp-for-specific-matching-of-character-string ... aside from the number of characters you want to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match ASCII letters and digits try the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

If letters and digits outside of the ASCII character set are required then the following should suffice:

```
^[^\W_]{3}(>[^\W_]{3})?$
```

Comment: Note that this pattern assumes that the string occupies a whole line. Otherwise, omit the `^` and/or `$`, but hen you have to exclude a possible `>` after the second letters group.

Comment: This only matches ASCII letters and digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\w+(?:>\w+)?$
```

matches an entire string.

```
\w+(?:>\w+)?\b(?!>)
```

matches strings like this in a larger substring.

If you want to exclude the underscore from matching, you can use `[\p{L]\p{N}]` instead (if your regex engine knows Unicode), or `[^\W_]` if it doesn't, as a substitute for `\w`.

Comment: \w also matches _ in addition to [A-Za-z0-9].

Comment: That won't match the first entry.

Comment: @djechlin: True, but then `ä` is a letter, too, and `[a-z]` won't match that.